# Hibernate: get subclass from discriminator?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the classic table per class hierarchy mapping in Jpa/Hibernate:

The father of all is:

```
@Entity
@Table( name="products", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="barcode") )
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name="discriminator",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="GENERAL")
public class Product implements Serializable ...
```

Then I'll have:

```
@Entity
@Table( name="products" )
@DiscriminatorValue("GLASS")
public class Sunglasses extends Product ...
```

Now I ask you: one day I will need to determine if a given **Product** is a **Sunglasses** or some other product type. I suppose "discriminator" is here for that but....

How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply return the type of the entity in a getter method:

```
public ProductType getType() {
    return ProductType.PRODUCT;
}

...

@Override
public ProductType getType() {
    return ProductType.SUN_GLASSES;
}
```

But the question is: why do you need to do that? The Product sould be used in a polymorphic way. The visitor pattern helps in doing that.

BTW, note that even if the returned type is SUN_GLASSES, casting the product to SunGlasses could fail if the reference is a lazy proxy.

Comment: " The Product sould be used in a polymorphic way. The visitor pattern helps in doing that." can you help me understand better? maybe with some good readings :)

Comment: I just posted a [blog post](http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2012/12/27/visitor-pattern-et-jpa/) about that. It's in French, but it's full of Java code and diagrams in English, so with the help of Google translate, you should be able to figure out what it all means.

Comment: One question: why should the casting fail in the event of the class being a lazy proxy? Maybe I am wrong, but I thought that the lazy proxy would be a subclass of `SunGlass` (if it returned `ProductYpe.SUN_GLASSES`)

Comment: Have you tried reading the blog post I linked to in my previous comment? It explains it in details.